# open appengine file in netbeans

Tags: google-app-engine, netbeans

From the appengine launcher on Windows, one of the buttons at the top is 'edit'. You can set the external editor in 'preferences'. The default is Wordpad. I wanted to use netbeans, but I can't figure out how to make GAE open netbeans. I have done many searches but I keep getting hits about creating a .exe file in netbeans, which is not what I want. I see no 'netbeans.exe' file. I tried C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.3.1\platform\core\core.jar but that does nothing. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

netbeans is a GUI for java SDK. it is not a text editor. it has a text editor somewhere in it, but it is not obvious where and it may not be possible to call the editor alone from outside.

I suggest you start netbeans, edit the file in it and then either launch the project from the launcher or from the command line. no need to compile, as soon as you save the edit, you can re-load the page.